# Read a txt file in app using only Scanner

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

I need to read file that stays in my app, and I want to use `Scanner`, but I have a problem when I put it in `assets` or `res`.

This is my part of code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zapis {
    public void zapis() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("assets/glvanii_ekran/glavnii_ekran.txt");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine() == true){
            MainActivity.list.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem you are having?

Comment: Also what did you put in assets or res?

Comment: When it start, on screen i have ListView with only one string : file:///android_asset/glvanii_ekran/glavnii_ekran.txt
Or anothrer directory, i put txt file

Answer (score 1):

Open your asset using an InputStream and then wrap it with a Scanner, as follows:

```
InputStream myFile = getResources().getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/glvanii_ekran/glavnii_ekran.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
```

Comment: When it start, on screen i have ListView with only one string :
file:///android_asset/glvanii_ekran/glavnii_ekran.txt

Comment: Wait a minute... what is MainActivity? Is it a local instance of the running activity or are you simply calling a static variable you declared? If the latter is the answer, it obviously won't work. If you could update the question with the full source code it would be helpful

Comment: No, i have to classes MainActivity and Zapis, and i want read file in class Zapis

Comment: It says : The method getResources() is undefined for the type Zapiz

Comment: OK, your problem is more basic: 1) MainActivity is a class (extending an Activity). If you wish to manipulate its contents from another class you have to access its running instance. For that, you need the zapis() constructor to receive the actual list, or a reference to the running activity altogether. 2) getResources() requires an instance with a valid Context (you should read about it in Google). Just pass a context to the constructor and call context.getResources()...

Comment: But my file is not Part of class? I can't understand, can you explain please/

Comment: This is beyond the scope of your question... I suggest that you read the article here and learn more about classes and instances to understand the problem: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/anatomy/static.html